# Does Tor change the Guard node (Entry node) if I connect my PC from a different IP address?

Tags: guard-node

Assume that I installed Tor on my PC and used it from IP1. I then bring my PC to another location and use Tor from IP2. So will my Three Guard Nodes be changed? If not, where in the packet can I find the information of these 3 Guard nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Lifecycle of a New Relay, clients rotate their guards every 4-8 weeks. Even though your IP is changing, the computer is still the same client, so I imagine it will use the same guards. However, I don't know where this information would be stored.

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay